# Why do I have the same button showing up in multiple locations on the page?

Tags: html, button

I am working on a simple calculator app using code pen. I am trying to make the keys such as `=` and `0` into buttons. So far I have only made the `=` and `ans` key into buttons. It turns both those keys into buttons, but they are also appearing at the top left of my page. Can someone clue me into whats going on, please?

Here is my pen:
http://codepen.io/roryavant8/pen/OMZjKR

Here is the HTML:

```
<div id="calculator">
</div>

<div id="resultBar">
</div>


<div id="numericOne" class="triangle-up">
  <p id="AC"><b>AC</b></p>
</div>


<div id="numericTwo" class="triangle-up">
  <p id="CE"><b>CE</b></p>
</div>

<div id="numericThree" class="triangle-up">
  <p id="percentage"><b>%<b></p>
</div>

<div id = "numericFour" class="triangle-up">
  <p id = "backSlash" ><b>/</b>
    <p>
</div>

<div id="numericFive" class="triangle-up">
  <p id="seven"><b>7</b></p>
</div>

<div id="numericSix" class="triangle-up">
  <p id="eight"><b>8</b></p>
</div>

<div id="numericSeven" class="triangle-up">
  <p id="nine"><b>9</b></p>
</div>

<div id="numericEight" class="triangle-up">
  <p id="asterik"><b>*</b></p>
</div>

<div id="numericNine" class="triangle-up">
  <p id="four"><b>4</b></p>
</div>

<div id="numericTen" class="triangle-up">
  <p id="five"><b>5</b></p>
</div>

<div id="numericEleven" class="triangle-up">
  <p id="six"><b>6</b></p>
</div>

<div id="numericTwelve" class="triangle-up">
  <p id="minus"><b>-</b></p>
</div>

<div id="numericThirteen" class="triangle-up">
  <p id="one"><b>1</b></p>
</div>

<div id="numericFourteen" class="triangle-up">
  <p id="two"><b>2</b></p>
</div>

<div id="numericFifteen" class="triangle-up">
  <p id="three"><b>3</b></p>
</div>

<div id="numericSixteen" class="triangle-up">
  <p id="plus"><b>+</b></p>
</div>

<div id="numericSeventeen" class="triangle-up">
  <p id="period"><b>.</b></p>
</div>

<div id="numericEighteen" class="triangle-up">
  <p id="zero"><b>0</p></b>
</div>

<button>
  <div id="numericNineteen" class="triangle-up">
    <p id="ans"><b>Ans</b>
      <p>
  </div>
</button>

<button>
  <div id="numericTwenty" class="triangle-up">
    <p id="equals"><b>=</b></p>
  </div>
</button>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
#calculator{ 
   left:50%;
   margin-left: -188px; 
   z-index: -1; 
   position:absolute;
   display:block;
   width: 400px;
   height: 500px;
   background-color: black;
   -webkit-border-radius: 63px 63px 63px 63px / 108px 108px 72px 72px;
   border-radius:         50%  50%  50%  50%  / 60%   60%   40%  40%;
}

#resultBar{
  position:absolute;
  width:150px;
  background-color:lime;
  height:30px;
  top:45px;
  left: 610px;
  border-radius:10px;
  box-shadow: inset 1px 0px 5px 1px white;
}

.triangle-up {

  width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 25px solid transparent;
    border-right: 25px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 50px solid lime;
  z-index: 1;

}

#numericOne{
    position:absolute;
    left:575px;
    top:100px;
}

#numericTwo{
  position:absolute;
  top:100px;
  left:635px;
}

#numericThree{
  position:absolute;
  top:100px;
  left:695px;
}

#numericFour{
  position:absolute;
  top:100px;
  left:755px;
}

#numericFive{
  position:absolute;
  top:170px;
  left:575px;
}

#numericSix{
  position:absolute;
  top:170px;
  left:635px;
}

#numericSeven{
  position:absolute;
  top:170px;
  left: 695px;
}

#numericEight{
  position:absolute;
  top:170px;
  left:755px;
}

#numericNine{
  position:absolute;
  top:240px;
  left:575px;
}

#numericTen{
  position:absolute;
  top:240px;
  left: 635px;
}

#numericEleven{
  position:absolute;
  top:240px;
  left:695px;
}

#numericTwelve{
  position:absolute;
  top:240px;
  left:755px;
}

#numericThirteen{
  position:absolute;
  top:310px;
  left:575px;
}

#numericFourteen{
  position:absolute;
  top:310px;
  left:635px;
}

#numericFifteen{
  position:absolute;
  top:310px;
  left:695px;
}

#numericSixteen{
  position:absolute;
  top:310px;
  left:755px;
}

#AC{
  position:relative;
  color:black;
  top:10px;
  right:12px;

}

#CE{
  position:relative;
  color:black;
  top:10px;
  right:12px;
}

#percentage{
  position:relative;
  color:black;
  top:10px;
  right:8px;
}

#backSlash{
  position:relative;
  color:black;
  top:10px;
  right: 3px;
  }

#seven{
  position:relative;
  color:black;
  top:10px;
  right:5px;
}

#eight{
  top:10px;
  right:5px;
  position:relative;
}

#nine{
  position:relative;
  top:10px;
  right:5px;
}

#asterik{
  position:relative;
  top:10px;
  right:5px;
}

#four{
  position:relative;
  top:10px;
  right:5px;
}

#five{
  position:relative;
  top:10px;
  right:5px;
}

#six{
  position:relative;
  top:10px;
  right:5px;
}

#minus{
  position: relative;
  top: 10px;
  right: 3px;
}

#one{
  position:relative;
  top: 10px;
  right: 3px;
}

#two{
  position:relative;
  top: 10px;
  right:  3px;
}

#three{
  position:relative;
  top: 10px;
  right: 4px;
}

#plus{
  position:relative;
  top: 10px;
  right: 4px;
}

#numericSeventeen{
  position:absolute;
  left: 575px;
  top: 380px;
}

#numericEighteen{
  position:absolute;
  left: 635px;
  top: 380px;
}

#numericNineteen{
  position:absolute;
  left: 695px;
  top: 380px;
}

#numericTwenty{
  position:absolute;
  left: 755px;
  top: 380px;
 }

#period{
  position:relative;
  top:5px;
  right: 1px;
}

#zero{
  position:relative;
  top:6px;
  right: 4px;
}

#ans{
  position:relative;
  top: 6px;
  right: 14px
}

#equals{
  position: relative;
  top: 10px;
  right: 4px;
}

#calculator{
  border-style: solid;
  border-color:lime;
  box-shadow:  5px 7px 5px 1px grey,
    inset 2px 2px 10px 0px grey;
}

.remove-background{
  background:none;
  border:none;
}

button{
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

Comment: Your markup should be improved. But if you need a quick solution
Just add `position:relative` to `id="calculator"`

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove your button tag, inside the HTML, both opening and closing at line : 
- 7 
- 11 
- 83 
- 88 
- 90, and lastly 
- 94

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign class and id for button. but you have given button inside div. so buttons are created without label. so you have to change you code like the below.

```
<button id="numericNineteen" class="triangle-up">
Ans
</button>
```

since label are not visible due to height and width set to 0. you need to use button background like triangle shape instead of applying style.

Answer (score 0):

I have some changes `CSSS & HTML` structure

```css
#calculator {
            left: 50%;
            margin-left: -188px;
            z-index: -1;
            position: absolute;
            display: block;
            width: 400px;
            height: 500px;
            padding-left: 80px;
            background-color: black;
            -webkit-border-radius: 63px 63px 63px 63px / 108px 108px 72px 72px;
            border-radius: 50% 50% 50% 50% / 60% 60% 40% 40%;
        }


        #resultBar {
            background-color: lime;
            border-radius: 10px;
            box-shadow: 1px 0 5px 1px white inset;
            height: 30px;
            margin: 37px auto 37px 80px;
            width: 150px;
        }


        .triangle-up {
            border-bottom: 50px solid lime;
            border-left: 25px solid transparent;
            border-right: 25px solid transparent;
            float: left;
            height: 0;
            margin-bottom: 20px;
            margin-right: 31px;
            width: 0;
            z-index: 1;
        }

        /*#numericOne {
            position: absolute;
            left: 575px;
            top: 100px;
        }

        #numericTwo {
            position: absolute;
            top: 100px;
            left: 635px;
        }

        #numericThree {
            position: absolute;
            top: 100px;
            left: 695px;
        }

        #numericFour {
            position: absolute;
            top: 100px;
            left: 755px;
        }

        #numericFive {
            position: absolute;
            top: 170px;
            left: 575px;
        }

        #numericSix {
            position: absolute;
            top: 170px;
            left: 635px;
        }

        #numericSeven {
            position: absolute;
            top: 170px;
            left: 695px;
        }

        #numericEight {
            position: absolute;
            top: 170px;
            left: 755px;
        }

        #numericNine {
            position: absolute;
            top: 240px;
            left: 575px;
        }

        #numericTen {
            position: absolute;
            top: 240px;
            left: 635px;
        }

        #numericEleven {
            position: absolute;
            top: 240px;
            left: 695px;
        }

        #numericTwelve {
            position: absolute;
            top: 240px;
            left: 755px;
        }

        #numericThirteen {
            position: absolute;
            top: 310px;
            left: 575px;
        }

        #numericFourteen {
            position: absolute;
            top: 310px;
            left: 635px;
        }

        #numericFifteen {
            position: absolute;
            top: 310px;
            left: 695px;
        }

        #numericSixteen {
            position: absolute;
            top: 310px;
            left: 755px;
        }*/

        #AC {
            position: relative;
            color: black;
            top: 10px;
            right: 12px;
        }

        #CE {
            position: relative;
            color: black;
            top: 10px;
            right: 12px;
        }

        #percentage {
            position: relative;
            color: black;
            top: 10px;
            right: 8px;
        }

        #backSlash {
            position: relative;
            color: black;
            top: 10px;
            right: 3px;
        }

        #seven {
            position: relative;
            color: black;
            top: 10px;
            right: 5px;
        }

        #eight {
            top: 10px;
            right: 5px;
            position: relative;
        }

        #nine {
            position: relative;
            top: 10px;
            right: 5px;
        }

        #asterik {
            position: relative;
            top: 10px;
            right: 5px;
        }

        #four {
            position: relative;
            top: 10px;
            right: 5px;
        }

        #five {
            position: relative;
            top: 10px;
            right: 5px;
        }

        #six {
            position: relative;
            top: 10px;
            right: 5px;
        }

        #minus {
            position: relative;
            top: 10px;
            right: 3px;
        }

        #one {
            position: relative;
            top: 10px;
            right: 3px;
        }

        #two {
            position: relative;
            top: 10px;
            right: 3px;
        }

        #three {
            position: relative;
            top: 10px;
            right: 4px;
        }

        #plus {
            position: relative;
            top: 10px;
            right: 4px;
        }

        /*#numericSeventeen {
            position: absolute;
            left: 575px;
            top: 380px;
        }

        #numericEighteen {
            position: absolute;
            left: 635px;
            top: 380px;
        }

        #numericNineteen {
            position: absolute;
            left: 695px;
            top: 380px;
        }

        #numericTwenty {
            position: absolute;
            left: 755px;
            top: 380px;
        }*/

        #period {
            position: relative;
            top: 5px;
            right: 1px;
        }

        #zero {
            position: relative;
            top: 6px;
            right: 4px;
        }

        #ans {
            position: relative;
            top: 6px;
            right: 14px;
        }

        #equals {
            position: relative;
            top: 10px;
            right: 4px;
        }

        #calculator {
            border-style: solid;
            border-color: lime;
            box-shadow: 5px 7px 5px 1px grey, inset 2px 2px 10px 0px grey;
        }

        .remove-background {
            background: none;
            border: none;
        }

        button {
            background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) none repeat scroll 0 0;
            border: 0 none;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
```

```html
<div id="calculator">


        <div id="resultBar">
        </div>


        <div id="numericOne" class="triangle-up">
            <button>
                <p id="AC"><b>AC</b></p>
            </button>
        </div>



        <div id="numericTwo" class="triangle-up">
            <p id="CE"><b>CE</b></p>
        </div>

        <div id="numericThree" class="triangle-up">
            <p id="percentage"><b>%</b></p>
        </div>

        <div id="numericFour" class="triangle-up">
            <p id="backSlash"><b>/</b>
            <p>
        </div>

        <div id="numericFive" class="triangle-up">
            <p id="seven"><b>7</b></p>
        </div>

        <div id="numericSix" class="triangle-up">
            <p id="eight"><b>8</b></p>
        </div>

        <div id="numericSeven" class="triangle-up">
            <p id="nine"><b>9</b></p>
        </div>

        <div id="numericEight" class="triangle-up">
            <p id="asterik"><b>*</b></p>
        </div>

        <div id="numericNine" class="triangle-up">
            <p id="four"><b>4</b></p>
        </div>

        <div id="numericTen" class="triangle-up">
            <p id="five"><b>5</b></p>
        </div>

        <div id="numericEleven" class="triangle-up">
            <p id="six"><b>6</b></p>
        </div>

        <div id="numericTwelve" class="triangle-up">
            <p id="minus"><b>-</b></p>
        </div>

        <div id="numericThirteen" class="triangle-up">
            <p id="one"><b>1</b></p>
        </div>

        <div id="numericFourteen" class="triangle-up">
            <p id="two"><b>2</b></p>
        </div>

        <div id="numericFifteen" class="triangle-up">
            <p id="three"><b>3</b></p>
        </div>

        <div id="numericSixteen" class="triangle-up">
            <p id="plus"><b>+</b></p>
        </div>

        <div id="numericSeventeen" class="triangle-up">
            <p id="period"><b>.</b></p>
        </div>

        <div id="numericEighteen" class="triangle-up">
            <p id="zero"><b>0</b></p>
        </div>


        <div id="numericNineteen" class="triangle-up">
            <button>
                <p id="ans"><b>Ans</b>
                <p>
            </button>
        </div>



        <div id="numericTwenty" class="triangle-up">
            <button>
                <p id="equals"><b>=</b></p>
            </button>
        </div>

    </div>
```